# Strange white text in IE7 and IE8

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem with some text that is meant to be black. Only in IE7 and IE8 is the text white (in IE6 it is black).

The text is in a paragraph within a slideshow and I've tried all I can think of; pointing at it very specifically with CSS and doing color:#000;. I also tried pointing at it with jQuery to no avail. When I load the page, it begins as black then instantly turns white.

Many Thanks

Comment: Okay... when you tried everything in your code... try checking your webbrowser's default text-color and set it to the correct color.

Comment: yeh but **if i am a viewer it still wont look right**.  It would be stupid to have a button saying to everyone change your default browser color.

Comment: Thats not the point. The point is that maybe HIS browser has the wrong settings.

Comment: I was hoping it was my computer or settings but the text on other computers is white too. The only way around it so far is to turn the white background black in IE8 and below, but I'd rather not do that if I can help it

Comment: this probably wont do anything but you could try color: black;

Comment: The only difference between this and the mockup html/css I did (that worked) is I had to make one of the parents of the p tag position:absolute;. Could that be anything to do with it?

Comment: The site you pointed to is under maintenance. Can you please attach a screenshot and the relevant code to your question?

Comment: Did you seriously put a bitly link to a domain that's shorter than the bitly link itself?

Answer (score 1):

I finally cracked it! It was to do with a CSS opacity filter. It's strange though because the opacity filter was set to the **element's sibling**.

ex:

```
<h3 (opacity set on bg of this, given height, absolute position etc) >
Bla bla bla</h3>
<div (absolutely positioned above h3 sibling) >
    <div>
        <p>Problem text here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried setting the z-index of the div to be on top of the h3 but it doesn't work in IE8 and 7. Anyway, applying `filter:none;` in my IE8 stylesheet HAS worked! :)

Answer (score 0):

try giving the p tag direct styling

```
<p style="color: #000 !important;">hjskhjakfhjkshfjdhkja</p>
```

Comment: Still white even with that I'm afraid!

Comment: I just tried adding a direct style but still no luck.. this is very weird!

Answer (score 0):

Okay maybe another try:

You said it switches to white suddenly... Do you have some code in your jQuery file, that triggers after the page is loaded completely?

And another way to find out where the problem is located: disable js or css in the development settings and see what happens.

Comment: That seems to have gotten me closer thank you. When javascript is disabled the text is black. I have one problem now... finding out what javascript is doing it! Is there any quick way you know of identifying javascript that turns things white?

Comment: In Firefox I would start the debug console in Firebug and look when the transition to white happens (place breakpoint at the beginning and step through the code). Please +1 helpful answers ;)

Comment: Thank you - I'll give it a go.. I tried +1 but it told me I didn't have enough rep!

Comment: I finally cracked it! It was to do with a CSS opacity filter. It's strange though because the opacity filter was set to the **element's sibling**.

ex:

    <h3 (opacity set on bg of this, given height, absolute position etc) >
    Bla bla bla</h3>
    <div (absolutely positioned above h3 sibling) ><div>
    <p>Problem text here</p>
    </div></div>

I tried setting the z-index of the div to be on top of the h3 but that doesn't work in IE8 and 7. Anyway.. applying 'filter:none;' in my ie8 stylesheet HAS worked! Hurray! :)